# Using AngularJS with jQuery and CSS Frameworks

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I'm looking to use a CSS framework like Foundation for my site but I really like the way AngularJS adds to the UX on forms, so I'd like to use AngularJS only in certain sections of the site.

I've read that Foundation doesn't play nice with AngularJS so I'm looking into Bootstrap with Angular-UI.

Is it possible to run jQuery alongside AngularJS if the two don't interact and control separate elements on the page?

Comment: Required reading if you're getting started with Angular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: JQuery works the same with or without AngularJS. It is usually just unnecessary with the built in power that is provided with Angular. But yes, you can use JQuery and it works just fine.

Comment: @ZackArgyle yeah but there are so many more plugins written or jQuery is the reason

Comment: @Dex can use foundation, jQuery plugins etc in angular. What you have to do though is think angular first. If you think jQuery first you make app far more complex than needed and run into all sorts of issues. Initializing any plugins should almost always be done from within a directive. The main problems arise trying to use frameworks that self initialize widgest from data attributes. Don't consider self initalizing them on page load, use their js plugin calls to do it

Comment: as side note...once you start working with angular will realize how much easier many tasks are than strictly using jQuery. Also won't need jQuery very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone just left comments so I'll close this out.

The answer is Yes.